# System.getenv() returns null

Tags: java, mysql, openshift

I'm trying through a Java applet to connect to a Mysql database set up on OpenShift.

```
String dbHost = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");
String dbPort = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
```

both of those strings return NULL when the application is online.
If I connect through ssh to the database everything seems to be working fine, I can see the database and I can work  on it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your database has nothing to do with that problem. Your application just can't find these environment variables.

Comment: Try doing a stop and start on your application using the rhc command line tool.  Sometimes that helps if you added the mysql cartridge after you had deployed code.

Answer (score 0):

1) what does `echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` give if you connect via ssh? You might use this as a default (for starters)

```
dbHost = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST") != null 
         System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST") : "defaultvalue";
```

2) try to `export OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=yourhostname`

Comment: Poor formatting (fixed), and possibly incomplete answer, but this is a valid attempt to answer the question nonetheless.