# Spring app with hibernate in Openshift - SQLException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, openshift

I have an Spring with hibernate which is deployed in openshift. when i access my application System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST") is showing null in console.
[Please see the below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfOnb.png.)
My Spring Mvc Datasorce file as below.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
public class DbConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dbSorce() {

         String
         dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://"+System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST")+
         ":"+System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT")+"/springmvc2k";
        System.out.println("dbUrl" + dbUrl);
        // String dbUrl = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL");
        String dbUsername = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
        String dbPassword = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");
        System.out.println("dbUsername" + dbUsername);
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Please help me to proceed.

Comment: Is the OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME defined as an environment variable ?

Comment: By default all the values are set in openshift .Please see the below link.https://developers.openshift.com/databases/mysql.html

Comment: did you add the cartridge?

Comment: Does echoing `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` returns a value?

Comment: yes i can able access in from local mysql. as well as cmd.

Comment: Try doing `rhc app stop <yourApp>` and `rhc app start <yourApp>`. It may help, if you added the mysql cartridge after you had deployed the code. ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431971/system-getenv-returns-null))

Comment: I tried .It is not working. System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST") is still showing null in console.

Comment: That MYSQL username and password is the top-level DBA username and password -- you may not want to use those (too many rights), instead log into MYSQL, create a new user with the roles necessary, and then just hardcode those credentials in.  Likewise the host and port you can probably determine their values from the cmd line and just paste them in--I've hosted a [blog](https://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/date/20131216#ROL4) on OpenShift for 2+ years now and those values have *never* changed for me no matter how many app start/stops.

Comment: Thanks .. that works... !!!